# How to read null for null-able Boolean values

Tags: c#, sql, nullable, dbnull

I am trying to read nullable values from a database.  Right now my code is converting null values to false.  How can I modify my code to allow for null values?

```
Ap1ExamTaken = dr["AP1_ExamTaken"] != DBNull.Value && Convert.ToBoolean(dr["AP1_ExamTaken"]),
```

I would like values that are null to be shown as null and not false.

Comment: What is the type of `Ap1ExamTaken`?

Comment: it is type bool?

Comment: You say you want to show the value but in the code snippet I cannot see anything, that shows it. There's just an assignment.

Comment: Basically if the db value is null I want Ap1ExamTaken to equal null other wise it'll equal true/false.

Comment: `Ap1ExamTaken = dr.Field<bool?>("AP1_ExamTaken")`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Is that assuming that `dr` is a `DataRow`? I'd been assuming `SqlDataReader` or similar.

Comment: @JonSkeet: It is indeed; force of habit of seeing this exact kind of code many, many times. (More so than for a data reader, in any case.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the conditional operator here, to set it to null if the value is `DBNull.Value`, or a non-nullable value otherwise:

```
Ap1ExamTaken = dr["AP1_ExamTaken"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (bool?) dr["AP1_ExamTaken"];
```

Note that this will throw an exception if `dr["AP1_ExamTaken"]` is a non-boolean, non-DBNull type, which I *suspect* is what you want.

You *could* write it more compactly as:

```
Ap1ExamTaken = dr["AP1_ExamTaken"] as bool?
```

... but then you'll end up with a null value if the value is some other type (a string, an integer etc) which I'd generally be alarmed about. (If my data doesn't have the shape I expect, I want to know ASAP.)